# How to apply a map reduce approach in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, montecarlo

I try to perform a Monte Carlo computation in parallel using python. The problem is an extremely parallel: I need to compute a function N times and add the output together, each computation is independent and the addition is a simple addition between tables.

So far I have tried two approaches:

1. Using `multiprocessing.map()`  and then python `reduce`. The problem is that I run out of memory because map is storing all the data even if I do not need to.
   The code looks like this:

   ```
   from multiprocessing import Pool
   import tqdm
   import numpy as np

   n_cpu = 8
   pool = Pool(n_cpu)
   out1 = list(tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(f, args, chunksize = 1000)))
   out = reduce(np.add, out1)
   ```

   This way I obtain a poor scaling with `n_cpu` and the code crashes for a memory error if the input size `len(args)` is too large.
2. I tried to solve using `pyspark` and the following code:

   ```
   import pyspark, findspark
   import numpy as np

   findspark.init()
   number_cores = 8
   memory_gb = 8
   conf = (
       pyspark.SparkConf()
           .setMaster('local[{}]'.format(number_cores))
           .set('spark.driver.memory', '{}g'.format(memory_gb))
   )
   sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
   out = sc.parallelize(range(N_samples)).repartition(number_cores).map(function).reduce(lambda a, b: np.add(a, b))
   ```

The repartition is done explicitly for clarity and is equal to the number of cores because I thought this is the best way to do it since the function to compute is computationally heavy.
The problem is that I obtain similar performance to the `multiprocessing` method.

My question is:
Is there a method to make the code scale better with the number of cores? Is there a way to use multiprocessing `imap_unordered()` and reduce it before the computation is done?

Comment: StackOverflow is used to use an MCVE-formulated problem policy. The **M**inimum **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample of your *Problem-under-Test* is neither **C**, nor **V** - kindly review your post and + for both the `.map()` and the `.parallelize()` methods their respective, yet missing code of **`def f( args ): ...`** for the former, plus a **`def function(): ...`** for the latter, also the **`N`** and **`args`** are undefined, yet used in the respective method's call-signatures above.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but to generalize your problem:

> You have 1 machine with multiple cores and you try to run some
>   algorithm and want to get best performance.

If the statement above is true - then Spark, most probably, is not what you need. Spark is primarily for distributed computing - i.e if you have multiple machines - then you can distribute your work and perform computations faster.

If you have only one machine - you can hardly get any better performance than any multithreaded approach, since Spark does a lot of stuff which is not required for single machine computations.